# Can I drill holes into the front of my fridge to attach a new handle?

Tags: refrigerator

I am going to attach contact paper to a fridge with no drilled holes. My old handle was glued on with two sided tape. I want to buy nice handles that will stay attached. Tape? Epoxy glue? Screws?

Comment: What's the contact paper got to do with it? I'm not clear on that.

Comment: I added a lower handle for a young nephew that used 9 little button-shaped super-magnets to attach. It holds more than strong enough.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the refrigerator, of course, but a typical sheet steel unit can take short sheet metal screws without issue. You'll want to be sure you don't penetrate any wiring, tubing, or the inner panel or seals.

I'd consider backing up the screws with the strength of permanent double-sided foam tape. Screws under regular strain tend to work loose over time, and the added stability this would provide would help prevent failure.